# wkhtmltopdf change the default size parameter from mm to pixels

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the wkhtmltopdf to convert the html to pdf.

I have design the html in pixel values.

But that does not shown properly when the pdf has build with wkhtmltopdf.

After some time, I got that it because the default size parameter of wkhtmltopdf is mm.

Now, question is how we could change to pixels, so that the design look exactly as we design in web.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Yes search lot for it, but no luck. Hence I put question here. Actually that option not found to me.

Comment: The same question give some clue about the solution. But I would like to know, is there any way to change wkhtmltopdf unit from "mm" to "pixel"

Comment: This is difficult, because PDF does not use pixels. Also, the end result depends on your resolution. I think the best options are to change your design, requirements and/or program. PrinceXML might be a better fit, but I don't have personal experience on it and it might still have the same issue.